# Does the holographic principle allow realistically-sized universe simulation?

Tags: quantum-information, universe, simulations, information, holographic-principle

I was reading about the holographic principle and a question came up to my mind which I can't find an answer to. My understanding is that the holographic principle states that the description volume of space can be encoded on its boundaries. What implications does this have on the *theoretical* lower boundary of computation time and memory complexity required to simulate any given volume of space? Can we simulate a physical system of N particles using a computer made out of K < N particles?

Comment: What boundary? The boundary exists in (a asimptotically) AdS spacetime, whose cosmological constant is negative per definition. Our universe has positive cosmological constant (dark energy)....

Comment: I see, then I don't understand what is the relevance of this principle if it's not applicable to our reality?

Comment: I am not the right person to ask it.. I think that it has theoretical relevance but no direct application to our universe, but this is just my superficial opinion. Maybe indirectt applications are possible. However frankly speaking I do not know. I hope somebody may properly reply, since that is a very popular subject, also in well known polular science journals. And I am very curious.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for adding color. Let's hope somebody more knowledgeable is able to provide more details